# cmake error ( fuerte in fedora 17 )

Tags: ros-fuerte, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

while running this command

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/fuerte -DSETUPTOOLS_DEB_LAYOUT=OFF
```

I got this

```
CMake Warning at build/cmake/rosunit/rosunit-extras.cmake:17 (message):
  add_pyunit() is deprecated.  For Python tests, use add_nostests() instead.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  ros_comm/test/test_rosbag/CMakeLists.txt:52 (add_pyunit)

-- +++ rx
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:97 (MESSAGE):
  **Could NOT find wxWidgets (missing: wxWidgets_FOUND)**
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:288 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake:831 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  rx/CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)
```

**noob alert**

how do I get past this !!  I have already have Diamondback and now I am trying to install fuerte ( on Fedora 17 ) without removing Diamondback
I am installing fuerte because I am confused whether the stacks openni_camera openni_tracker and openni_launch would work alright with Diamondback ... what I understand is the older stack openni_kinect is now divided into 2 - openni_camera  and openni_tracker  .. and their pages show install commands only for fuerte
also there is more support for fuerte now i think

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45237/cmake-error---(-fuerte-in-fedora-17-)/) by [codeit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3334/codeit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-10-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I went through the process of installing Fuerte on Fedora 17 yesterday and had to install A LOT of additional libraries. This particular dependency was resolved by installing wxWidgets, wxPython, wxPython-devel, if I remember correctly.

---

Originally posted by [Mat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3457/mat/) with karma: 26 on 2012-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FranciscoD](https://answers.ros.org/users/3235/franciscod/) on 2013-03-20**:
Only wxGTK-devel seems to be sufficient. I just ran into this error and installing this one package solved it.

EDIT: The make command failed requiring wxPython. Heh.